# How do you use Javascript to change the background on a html Table

Tags: javascript, html

[HTML Table that is happening now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNVc1.png) 
I'm trying to take this HTLM table with numbers on it the first column added to the second equals the third. some of the sum column are not correct. the correct answer is in the fourth column. I need to use Javascript to change the background color of the rows that are not correct and add in the correct number? This is what I have so far? The attached picture is what is coming up to far.

[This picture is what the HTML Table is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPFxX.png)

Please help

```
        for (var m = 0; m < math.length; m++) {
                    // math[m][0] = the first element of the m-th array (indices start at 0)
                    // math[m][1] = the second element of the m-th array
                    // math[m][2] = the third element of the m-th array
            document.write(math[m][0] + ' + ' + math[m][1] + ' = ' + math[m][2]  + "<br>" +' Actual answer =  '+ (math[m][0]+ math[m][1])+ "<br>");
               }        
</script>   

    <table class="mathTable" id="math" style="width:80%"; border="1em";>
    <tr>
        <th>1st Number</th>
        <th>2nd Number</th>
        <th>Answer</th>
        <th>Actual Answer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='calculation'>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>8</td>    
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='calculation'>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>13</td>    
        <td>13</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr class='calculation'>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>10</td>    
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
<!--    needs background color change-->
    <tr class='calculation'>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>13</td>    
        <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='calculation'>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>11</td>    
        <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='calculation'>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>12</td>    
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
<!--    needs background color change-->
    <tr class='calculation'>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>12</td>    
        <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='calculation'>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>    
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
        <tr class='calculation'>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>14</td>    
        <td>14</td>
    </tr>
        <tr class='calculation'>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>12</td>    
        <td>12</td>
              </tr> 
        </table>
    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show where you're trying to use Javascript to change the background color? I don't see anything doing anything like that in the code

Comment: That could be my problem. What would I add to change the background color on the improper numbers? I was told to use a for counter loop to find the calculations and that I have to convert the page data to numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Tables are made up of `rows` and `cells`.
It's a good idea to use the `thead` and `tbody` tags in your table,
and recommended to separate the css from the body elements

to change the background color: add a class to the element with the chosen color

```js
const tableMath = document.getElementById('table-math');

for (let line=1; line < tableMath.rows.length; line++)
  {
  if ( tableMath.rows[line].cells[2].textContent != tableMath.rows[line].cells[3].textContent )
    {
    tableMath.rows[line].cells[3].classList.add('badAnswer')
    }
  }
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em;
  }
td,th {
  border: solid grey 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  }
th {
  background-color: #7fffd5;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
  }
.badAnswer {
  background-color: #f47c6f;
  }
```

```html
<table id="table-math">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> 1st Number    </th>
      <th> 2nd Number    </th>
      <th> Answer        </th>
      <th> Actual Answer </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td>5</td> <td>3</td> <td> 8</td> <td> 8</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>7</td> <td>6</td> <td>13</td> <td>13</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>5</td> <td>5</td> <td>10</td> <td>10</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>8</td> <td>3</td> <td>13</td> <td>11</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>4</td> <td>7</td> <td>11</td> <td>11</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>3</td> <td>9</td> <td>12</td> <td>12</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>8</td> <td>5</td> <td>12</td> <td>13</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>2</td> <td>6</td> <td> 8</td> <td> 8</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>5</td> <td>9</td> <td>14</td> <td>14</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>6</td> <td>6</td> <td>12</td> <td>12</td> </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Mister Jojo this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Do I need to keep any of my original code (that isn't in your snippet)?

Comment: @JasmineChampagneLusty  all your JS part is wrong, and you have to remove style attributes in your table by using css...